# Renaming column names with number accounting for a non-sequential column name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, rename

I have a data like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- cars %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble()
dat <- dat %>%
  rename(dummy = V10)
dat
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 50
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9 dummy   V11   V12   V13
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     4     7     7     8     9    10    10    10    11    11    12    12
2     2    10     4    22    16    10    18    26    34    17    28    14    20
# … with 37 more variables: V14 <dbl>, V15 <dbl>, V16 <dbl>, V17 <dbl>, V18 <dbl>,
#   V19 <dbl>, V20 <dbl>, V21 <dbl>, V22 <dbl>, V23 <dbl>, V24 <dbl>, V25 <dbl>,
#   V26 <dbl>, V27 <dbl>, V28 <dbl>, V29 <dbl>, V30 <dbl>, V31 <dbl>, V32 <dbl>,
#   V33 <dbl>, V34 <dbl>, V35 <dbl>, V36 <dbl>, V37 <dbl>, V38 <dbl>, V39 <dbl>,
#   V40 <dbl>, V41 <dbl>, V42 <dbl>, V43 <dbl>, V44 <dbl>, V45 <dbl>, V46 <dbl>,
#   V47 <dbl>, V48 <dbl>, V49 <dbl>, V50 <dbl>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

I want the column names to be **"V8, V9, dummy, *V10*, *V11*..."**
How can I achieve this by manipulating column names? I'm wondering if I could **dplyr::rename_with** to do this, but I'm not sure how to write it.

Any help would be appriciated, thank you in advance.

Edit: I'd like to know if there's a way to do this **without relying on columns numbers (e.g. dat[10:49]) for specifying columns to rename,** since the actual data is much bigger and I have to do this for multiple series of items. Thank you Jon Spring for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of tinkering and help from the community, I was able to get it to work using:

```
res <- dat %>%
  rename_with(str_replace,
              pattern = "\\d+", replacement = function(x)
                (x %>%
                   str_subset("\\d+") %>%
                   as.numeric() - 1 %>%
                   return()),
              num_range("V", 10:50))
res %>%
  names()

 [1] "V1"    "V2"    "V3"    "V4"    "V5"    "V6"    "V7"    "V8"    "V9"    "dummy" "V10"   "V11"  
[13] "V12"   "V13"   "V14"   "V15"   "V16"   "V17"   "V18"   "V19"   "V20"   "V21"   "V22"   "V23"  
[25] "V24"   "V25"   "V26"   "V27"   "V28"   "V29"   "V30"   "V31"   "V32"   "V33"   "V34"   "V35"  
[37] "V36"   "V37"   "V38"   "V39"   "V40"   "V41"   "V42"   "V43"   "V44"   "V45"   "V46"   "V47"  
[49] "V48"   "V49"
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Using `regmatches` and its replacement mode:

```
rg <- regexpr("\\d+", names(dat))
regmatches(names(dat), rg) <- seq_along(rg)
dat
## A tibble: 2 × 50
#     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9 dummy   V10   V11   V12
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dat_names <- names(dat)
names(dat) = c(dat_names[1:9], "dummy", dat_names[10:49])
```

Or if you don't know which column position the to-be-replaced column is in, but you know its name:

```
dat_names <- names(dat)
col <- match("V10", dat_names)
names(dat) = c(dat_names[1:(col-1)], "dummy", 
               dat_names[(col+1):length(dat_names)])
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I'd like to find a solution that doesn't rely on column numbers for specifying the columns to rename, since the actual data is much bigger than the example. Edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: What fact(s) do you know about the column name you want to insert? Is the case, for instance, that you want it to replace the column currently called V10? Or that it follows V9? But you don't know it's the 10th column?

Comment: I would like to "insert" the "dummy" variable without breaking the sequence of column numbers. E.g.) I have V1, V2, V3... V10, and I want to insert "dummy" without this being like V1... V5, dummy, V7, V8... V10. Therefore, ideally I don't want to rely on manually specifing the succeding column number since it should be specified in accordance with the already existing sequence, but I could do it manually if that's necessary.

Comment: Then I think the 2nd solution does what you want? In that case "V10" is the name we know should become "dummy."

Answer (score 2):

This should be independent on the number, but it is depending on the name of the column after you want to rename with 'dummy':
This solution uses `rename_with` together with `append` and `match` function.
Basically we get the index of "V9" with `match` and then `append` it to colnames vector after this index:

```
library(dplyr)
cars %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename_with(., ~append(colnames(dat), "dummy", after = match("V9", colnames(dat))))
```

```
 [1] "V1"    "V2"    "V3"    "V4"    "V5"    "V6"    "V7"    "V8"    "V9"    "dummy" "V10"   "V11"   "V12"   "V13"   "V14"   "V15"  
[17] "V16"   "V17"   "V18"   "V19"   "V20"   "V21"   "V22"   "V23"   "V24"   "V25"   "V26"   "V27"   "V28"   "V29"   "V30"   "V31"  
[33] "V32"   "V33"   "V34"   "V35"   "V36"   "V37"   "V38"   "V39"   "V40"   "V41"   "V42"   "V43"   "V44"   "V45"   "V46"   "V47"  
[49] "V48"   "V49"
```